# Why is $l^2$ space needed in definition of weighted shift?

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces, orthonormal

Today I've come across [a definition of weighted shift](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeightedShift.html) on Wolfram MathWorld.

They define the weighted shift as the operator working with elements from the standard orthonormal basis the space $X$. And $X = l^2$.

My question is - Since the weighted shift is simply this operation:

$$
T e_n = \alpha_n e_{n+1},
$$

$T$ being the continuous linear operator and $e$ being an element from the space, where $T$ is defined... Isn't it enough to define this simple operation?

What's the exact point of defining elements for the operator like the elements of the space orthonormal basis and the space being especially $l^2$?

Comment: @πr8 So you think, that the point is to have a Hilbert space?

Comment: @πr8 And to be sure I understood you well, you mean the part describing, that every element from the space can be described with Fourier series?

Comment: @πr8 And do you think, it's even necessary to define weighted shift only for elements of orthonormal basis? I'd say we can "shift" elements of any set...

Comment: @πr8 Great, could you, please, formulate your reasoning into the answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice to use $l^2$is mostly so that they can make use of the inner product notation - such an operator makes plenty of sense on $l^1,l^∞$ and so on.

Comment: Well, no: it is not just or even mostly because of notation. It is because the space is a Hilbert space, which has tons of properties not shared by other Banach spaces.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I appreciate that it is a Hilbert space and that these have special properties, but I'm not sure why any of these are exclusive to the idea of a weighted shift operator - one can comfortably define such operators on most (all?) sequence spaces, no?

Comment: Indeed, but it is immensely unlikely that the choice of space is based on *notation*.